# Ordering stylesheet above <style> using functions.php

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-script

I'm loading a stylesheet and a `style` into the header using functions.php. This works but the stylesheet is being presented below the `<style>`. I need to order the stylesheet **above** the `style` block.

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Load CSS into header
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function folio_dynamic_css() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );

    ob_start();

    echo '<style type="text/css">';

    # css styles here

    echo '</style>';

    # compress CSS
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    echo preg_replace('/^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$/m', '', $output) ."\n";

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'folio_dynamic_css', 1 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be outputting anything on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook, just enqueueing. Move your css output to a function hooked to `wp_head` with a lower priority than 8, which is when the enqueued styles are printed in `wp_head`:

```
function folio_enqueue_css() {  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'folio_enqueue_css', 1 );

function folio_dynamic_css() {
    ob_start();
    echo '<style type="text/css">';
    # css styles here
    echo '</style>';
    # compress CSS
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    echo preg_replace('/^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$/m', '', $output) ."\n"; 
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'folio_dynamic_css', 20 );
```